# Excel track boolean changes

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA code to track changes in a workbook (and by-passing Excel's terrible Shared Workbook/Track Changes feature) using the code below:

```
Option Explicit
Dim sOldAddress As String
Dim vOldValue As Variant
Dim sOldFormula As String
```

Then

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wActSheet As Worksheet
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Set wActSheet = ActiveSheet

     'Precursor Exits
     'Other conditions that you do not want to tracke could be added here
    'If vOldValue = "" Then Exit Sub 'If you comment out this line *every* entry will be recorded
     'Continue

    On Error Resume Next ' This Error-Resume-Next is only to allow the creation of the tracker sheet.
    Set wSheet = Sheets("Workbook History")
     '**** Add the tracker Sheet if it does not exist ****

    If wSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set wActSheet = ActiveSheet
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Workbook History"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
     '**** End of specific error resume next

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Sheets("Workbook History")
         '******** This bit of code moves the tracker over a column when the first columns are full**'
        If .Cells(4, 1) = "" Then '
            iCol = 1 '
        Else '
            iCol = .Cells(4, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column - 7 '
            If Not .Cells(65536, iCol) = "" Then '
                iCol = .Cells(4, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 '
            End If '
        End If '
         '********* END *****************************************************************************'
        .Unprotect Password:="Secret"

         '******** Sets the Column Headers **********************************************************
        If LenB(.Cells(4, iCol).Value) = 0 Then
            .Range(.Cells(4, iCol), .Cells(4, iCol + 7)) = Array("Cell Changed", "Old Value", _
            "New Value", "Old Formula", "New Formula", "Time of Change", "Date of Change", "User")
            .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
        End If

        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            .Value = sOldAddress

                .Offset(0, 1).Value = vOldValue
                .Offset(0, 3).Value = sOldFormula

            If Target.Count = 1 Then
                    .Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Value

            If Target.HasFormula Then .Offset(0, 4).Value = "'" & Target.Formula
            End If

            .Offset(0, 5) = Time
            .Offset(0, 6) = Date
            .Offset(0, 7) = Application.UserName
            .Offset(0, 7).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With

         '.Protect Password:="Secret"  'Uncomment to protect the "tracker tab"

    End With
ErrorExit:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    wActSheet.Activate
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
     'any error handling you want
     'Debug.Print "We have an error"
    Resume ErrorExit

End Sub
```

Then

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target
        sOldAddress = "'" & .Parent.Name & "'!" & .Address(external:=False)

        If .Count > 1 Then
            vOldValue = "Multiple Cell Select"
            sOldFormula = vbNullString
        Else

            vOldValue = .Value

        If .HasFormula Then
            sOldFormula = "'" & Target.Formula
        Else
            sOldFormula = vbNullString
        End If

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

All in the ThisWorkbook object.

This works great! Unless the value that is changing on the worksheet is a TRUE/FALSE value. For example, I have some checkbox form controls on the worksheet that change a cell's value to TRUE/FALSE. I want to track when these values change, but the code above won't capture these changes. I've tried using several different If statements like If .Value = True Then "TRUE", etc. but it seems like the code isn't even recognizing the TRUE/FALSE changes as a change!

Any ideas on how to capture changes in TRUE/FALSE values in a range using VBA?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not about true/false values, it's about the fact the checkboxes do not raise `Worksheet_Change` when you click them. You need to handle click events on those in addition to what you have.

Comment: But all of the checkboxes on my worksheet are linked to cells, so when a box is check/unchecked it does change the cell's value to TRUE/FALSE

Comment: It does, but it magically bypasses the event. This is a known Excel gotcha.

Comment: Ah. Well it got me. That makes sense, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from GSerg's comment...

Place this code in the `ThisWorkbook` module and assign it to all of your checkboxes:

```
Public Sub CBClick()
    Dim addr As String

    addr = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).LinkedCell
    With ActiveSheet.Range(addr)
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

It should then trigger your existing `Change` event handler

EDIT: I just noticed you'll need to make some changes to mimic some of the actions in your selection change handler, but this should at least give you a start...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So, how would I handle this if I already have macros assigned to all of the checkboxes on the worksheet?

Comment: Depends on your existing macros and how many there are...  They could more or less replace my example, but that would depend on exactly how things are set up